# Combinations of adjacent ball pairs over a ring

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a ring composed by $n$ total sites, where each site can allocate at most 1 ball. We are looking for combinations where only 4 total balls can be put in the ring. Then $N_{4}^{n}$ ( the combinatoric "n chooses 4" ), is used to determine the total number of possible configurations.

Now we have a situation where the 4 balls will always be arranged in pairs. We put two balls at positions $(i,i+1)$, with $i$ fixed and $i\in[1,...,n]$. We allocate the other two balls always in pairs, at sites $(i+2,i+3),(i+3,i+4),...,(i-2,i-1)$, with a total of $n-3$ possible allocations. We then repeat this for all other possible values of $i$, i.e. by a single translation of the fixed pair to the next value of $i$, so that we start from $(i+1,i+2)$. Then, the other pairs will start to be allocated at $(i+3,i+4),(i+4,i+5),...,(i+1,i+2)$.

The question is, how many times does a given configuration $(i,i+1),(k,k+1)$ with $|k-i|>1$ repeat in this process, as a function of the total number of sites $n$ of the ring? Note that the way to allocate balls is always in pairs, with each pair consisting on neighbouring balls.

Comment: This is hard to follow (I only tried the first paragraph).  Is $k$ meant to be $4$?  Are the balls identical?  If the sites are arranged in a circle, are we to assume that rotated arrangements are equivalent?  That's standard for circular arrangements.  What about reflected arrangements?  Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: I have edited a bit the description. k is a generic index that runs over the possible vacancies along the ring, once the pair $(i,i+1)$ has been fixed. Then, for any value of $i$, there are $n-3$ possible values of k where new pairs can be allocated. The balls are identical, but we are asking about a configuration where $i,k$ have fixed values.

Comment: What you have written is simply not clear.  Only at the end do we learn that you are putting in the balls $2$ at a time next to each other, and I still have no guess as to what $k$ means in the first paragraph.  Also, please answer my questions about equivalent arrangements.  I suggest rewriting the post completely.   Maybe work the problem explicitly for some modest value of $n$, like $5$ or $6$, the smallest number that illustrates whatever it is you are asking about.

Comment: Are the balls distinguishable?

Comment: There are not reflected or rotated arrangements to be equivalent. The balls are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each configuration will repeat two times, because the only repeat comes from switching $i$ and $k$. For example, the configuration where $i=3$ and $k=5$ is repeated when you choose $i=5$ and $k=3$.

See this example when $n=5$:

| $i$ | $k$ | Configuration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1234 |
| 1 | 4 | 1245 |
| 2 | 4 | 2345 |
| 2 | 5 | 1235 |
| 3 | 5 | 1345 |
| 3 | 1 | 1234 |
| 4 | 1 | 1245 |
| 4 | 2 | 2345 |
| 5 | 2 | 1235 |
| 5 | 3 | 1345 |